# Why are column store indexes disabled automatically when a database is restored?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2019

I have recently done a server migration where we backed up and restored all the databases from a SQL Server 2012 version to SQL Server 2019. However the restored databases appear to all have their column store indexes disabled by default.

Is this expected behaviour? If so, why?

These are archive databases used for selects only, rebuilding every clustered index is going to take a significant amount of time. Any other options?

(sorry, I asked this in the wrong place [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61903411/why-are-column-store-indexes-disabled-automatically-when-a-database-is-restored). Can that question be removed?)

Comment: There is a somewhat-related fix in CU2 (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4528066/fix-unable-to-restore-sql-server-2012-databases-on-sql-server-2016-201).  What exact 2019 version are you using?

Comment: Haven't found any documentation yet, but my guess is that 2012 columnstores are so different from 2019 that the "fix" was to disable them when restored.

Comment: @TonyHinkle - ahhh that could be it. Am on CU1... oh dear god. That means best bet is to put in the latest CU, then re-restore all the databases again. Because rebuilding them is is probably going to take a couple of weeks...

Comment: @TonyHinkle - OK this didn't work. I installed CU4 and rebooted server. Restored one of the 2012 databases again and column store indexes still disabled on this database. Grrrrr....

Comment: Have submitted as a bug in the SQL Server user voice: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/40474993-column-store-indexes-disabled-when-upgrading-datab

Comment: If you do have to rebuild, you can replace the NCCIs with CCIs with archival compression and save a lot of space.